# Find files with specific codec using python and ffprobe

Tags: command-line, python, video

I am trying to find all video files with codec h264 in a directory with many sub directories.

I already have written some parts that work for a single file, but I want a report of all files in all the subdirectories from a folder.

Here is what I have for now:

```
import os
import sys
import json

inputPath = '/home/Videos/Vacation/2019 - 07/'

codec = 'h264'
type = 'video'

cmd = 'ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -print_format json ' + inputPath
output = os.popen(cmd).read()
output = json.loads(output)

for stream in output['streams']:
    if stream['codec_name'] == codec and stream['codec_type'] == type:
        print(inputPath)
        sys.exit(0)
```

But there are 2 problem where I hope someone can help:

1. The directories have spaces in them so I cannot pass them as is to the command and need to escape those characters. Is there an easy way to do this in Python?
2. I need to loop through all sub-directories and sub-sub...-directories for mkv- and mp4-files. What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Yes there is, 2. best is a matter of opinion. Coding questions should be asked on our sister site https://stackoverflow.com/  but if you type both of your question in google you do get results that will work. Both are pretty generic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` will do the tricks.  All you have to do is to specify a start directory and some parameters and use it in a `for` loop.

```
for dpath, dname, filenames in os.walk('/home/Videos/Vacation/2019 - 07/'):
    ...
```

From the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

```
 os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)

 Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree
 either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree
 rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a
 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
```